# В pycharm и webstorm наблюдаются визуальные глюки на manjaro

Tags: linux, pycharm, jetbrains, gnome, manjaro

Выглядит как зеленые глюки-квадраты возникают при скролле либо при нажатии(любом взаимодействии) [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как это решить? Что делать? Причем это еще и в gimp. Странно.
Иногда они жутко сильные и большие.
Тоже самое кстати и на ubuntu

Comment: GPU случайно не nvidia? Если оно то ставьте родной драйвер вместо nouveau

Comment: Что написано в **Help | About** в IDE про VM? `by JetBrains s.r.o.` или что-то другое?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена переустановкой через toolbox

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).